# How to start IISExpress for a web project without building?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have this scenario:

- I have a solution open, with a web project configured to use `IIS 
  Express`.
- I do a build of the solution, then close Visual Studio.
- I then reopen VS to that solution.

Is there a way to just spin up IIS Express without having to do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>F5</kbd> or something like that (I don't need to build again since I know nothing has changed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start IIS Express from Command Line. We can also configure different sites to run on specific ports. This article explains the process:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 4):

Get the name of the site from `C:\Users\<your user>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

in the `<sites>` section find the one you are working on

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /site:"<that thing you got from applicationhost.config>"
```

or on a 32bit OS

```
"c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /site:"<that thing you got from applicationhost.config>"
```